# Rails 5 add nonce to image_tag to whitelist CSP image-src violation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, content-security-policy

I am trying to whitelist an inline image. Is there a way to add nonce to [image_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag) like [javascript_include_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_include_tag)
to whitelist a inline image.

base on [CSP: img-src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/img-src), it mentioned `img-src` supports `'nonce-<base64-value>'`

My CSP policy for `image-src`

```
policy.img_src :self
```

I tried the following and confirmed that nonce shows up in the dom.

```
#fruist_store.html.haml

= image_tag('https://assets.myfruitstore.com', nonce: content_security_policy_nonce)
```

But the nonce on the `image_tag` does not seem to be honored unlike `script-src`. I am still getting

```
[Report Only] Refused to load the image 'https://assets.myfruitstore.com' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src self
```

I was wondering if there is another way to make this work or if that is something not secured to do.

**Update**:

So based on [Rails content_security_policy.rb#L134](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb#L134), it seems like Rails does NOT add nonce to to `image_src`

so I update my policy to

```
policy.img_src :self, -> {%(nonce-{request.content_security_policy_nonce})}
```

But still flagging it as a violation

Comment: You need to also ensure that the nonce is added to the Content-Security-Policy response header. You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to view the value of the response headers. Or if the system doesn’t send a Content-Security-Policy response header, check the value of the `meta httpequiv=Content-Security-Policy` element in the document itself. Maybe to get the nonce added in the right, place, you must adjust the `policy.img_src` value too. (I can’t be more specific because I don’t know any of the details of the system/library you’re relying on for generating the right CSP…)

Comment: O so Rails 5.2 added DSL for CSP. more details here https://blog.bigbinary.com/2018/10/23/rails-5-2-adds-dsl-for-configuring-content-security-policy-header.html . It also comes with a `content_security_policy_nonce_generator` helper to take care of generating nonce and I can just access it with `content_security_policy_nonce`